# How do I get a caption below a tikz circle?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a simple example like:

```
\begin{figure}    
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{scope}
            \draw (1, 3) circle (3);
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Caption}
\end{figure}
```

All I want to do is placing a caption below (or better more general in the south west, south east, north west, north east, ...) of the circle *boundary*. When I'm placing a node, then it is always in the center. How can I fix this?

Comment: Please add a [short, but compilable test file](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a `document` environment.  If I add enough code to make your code fragment compilable, I get the caption below the circle: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Skhxb.png

Comment: Unrelated: You should use `\draw (1, 3) circle[radius=3];`, not `\draw (1, 3) circle (3);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your circle using `node` and add `label`s at any angle using the code `label=<angle>:<labeltext>`. You can also add `[label distance=<length>]` to adjust the distance from the boudary.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw, circle, minimum size=3cm, 
    label=45:forty-five, 
    label=100:one hundred, 
    label={[label distance=6mm]270:bottom}]{center};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How do I set where the circle is centered?

Comment: before `{center}` you can add `at (3,2)` to center at those coordinates, or `at (A)` if there is already a node named `A` in your diagram.